# Exporting Adobe files to work in alternative platforms?

Tags: export, sketch-app, software-recommendation, creative-cloud, cross-platform

My Creative Cloud is going to run out soon and I'm looking into cheaper alternatives, such as Sketch, however I'm concerned about the files for current projects that I'm working on.

Can they be exported, or will I have to recreate the designs from scratch? They're mainly layered designs, logos and some photoshop gifs.

(Oh, and if you have any recommendations on alternative platforms!)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend Affinity Designer and Affinity Photo (I have no connection with Affinity, just a user). They can also open PSD and AI. I prefer the Designer over Illustrator. Haven't worked that much with Photo, but so far it seems like a really good alternative to Photoshop. The pricing model is also a lot better than Adobe's. The files are saved in a format that allow them to be opened in both Designer and Photo, and you can export to several different formats. Affinity is also working on an InDesign alternative.